# Pivot Table is not filling with data

Tags: pivot-table

I'm trying to create a simple Pivot Table and it was working at first, but now when I select the data field to use nothing populates the table. I have already made sure there are no filters and clicked the "clear all" button to ensure all filters were clears. Can anyone think of any reason this is happening?

[image: This is what I get after selecting the data field B2:E7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it working again. Saved it to a flashdrive and opened it on another desktop and is now working perfectly.